# Can I make some of my appointments not show up on the sidebar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, reminder, appointments

Fact 1) On the right hand side of my screen, I have the default setting of: Calendar, next couple appointments, flagged tasks, and frequent contacts (Lync integration).

Fact 2) Unfortunately, I don't have a parking pass and have to move my car to a different stall during lunch or face a ticket.

So what do these two random facts have to do with eachother? Well, I have two appointments, one at 11:40-11:41 and another at 1:40-1:41 to move my car. I do this so I am reminded twice each day, before and after lunch, to move my car and not spend half my check on parking tickets.

But having two appointments takes up valuable space in my list of "next couple appointments". There's only room for 3, and two are almost always used up by "Move your car".

So my question is - "Can I make these appointments not show up in that list"? And a related query if I can't is "Is there a better way to have a reoccurring reminder (that shows up in my "do do dooooo reminder box") that does not use appointments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a task to create recurring reminders, instead of appointments.

Create a task as usual, set the due date to today, and set a reminder at 1:40pm. Then click the Recurrence button.

Then you can set the recurrence pattern - you probably want it to either recur daily, or set it to weekly and pick which days of the week you would like it to recur on.

Save & Close, and you should see the task in your task list. When the reminder goes off at 1:40pm,  mark the task as complete, and a new task will be scheduled for tomorrow.

Comment: I've added my tasks at 11:40 and 1:40, we'll see if they show up in my reminder box like I need them to. Thanks!

Comment: This did the trick - I had to add the time to the due "date" so I make sure to get the 'time overdue or until' proper, but other than that this was solid! Thank you so much, this clears up my calendar for useful things, and people no longer avoid appointments at those times :D

Comment: Glad to help :)